# filesystem on Linux for SD card for Dropbox sync

Tags: linux, filesystems, sync, dropbox, sd-card

I have a super small drive on my ultraportable lenovo 100s. I want to sync several gb of stuff from my dropbox onto it, so I have equipped it with a [western digital purple sd card](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/memory-cards/wd-purple-microsd#WDD032G1P0C).

I plan to use that media as the storage device on which I will put my dropbox folder.

I am seeking advice on which filesystem to use given the possibly frequent refresh (read/write) activity of dropbox and the nature of sd card (not as resistent as hard drive). I am running a 32-bit Rapberry Pi OS, based on Debian 11.

I am aware of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/248078/choice-of-filesystem-for-gnu-linux-on-an-sd-card#248092) but it is a bit dated and not specific to my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever file-system you may use, be aware that SD cards are fragile.
Do not expect to use your card for a long time, and be prepared for it
to fail without notice.

Most file-systems will do, as long as you disable journaling.
Your card itself does wear-leveling, so this is not required in
the file-system and you could pick one that is simple and efficient.

You may find some information in the post
[Best File system for microSD used for snapshots & storage](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/umk511/best_file_system_for_microsd_used_for_snapshots/),
where a user detailed some statistics about his (terribly cheap)
SD cards that he used extensively:

> - EXT4 with journaling - 7 days
> - EXT4 w/o journaling - 12 days
> - BTRFS - 6 months
> - Read-only BTRFS with APT wrapper - survived 2 years, exceeding the test length

Seems like BTRFS is a good match. If you intend to use the card on
non-Linux computers, exFAT will do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for chiming in. I am a bit confused though from the redit post you linked. First of all I did not share at all the same trouble with Raspberry Pi and SD cards. I have run 4/5 raspberri pi 24/7 for years doing several things (printer server, home assistant, vpn server, media player, ... ) and burned SD cards only after years ...

Comment: For the other aspects discussed in that post I clearly see the fundamental reason why journaling affects the endurance of the card, but I do not see why BTRFS should stress less the SD card than ext4 without journaling. On the opposite it seems to me that copy-on-write in BTRFS may produce more writes than a fs without copy-on-write.

Comment: These are empirical results of an unknown person. For my money, you should use the most primitive file-system possible that will just write once and do nothing else. ExFAT is certainly primitive, but I don't know how well it would serve in your context.

Comment: I think I share the sentiment of going basic here, and was indeed considering exFAT as an option after your comment. As a matter of fact data is coming from dropbbox here and synced to it on the fly all the time, so its backup is guaranteed and instantaneous. On that side I am safe. I just want to avoid to overly wear a 50 bucks SD card too often...

Comment: The maker states "Capacities up to 1TB1. WD Purple microSD cards are built with advanced 96-layer 3D NAND technology, ensuring high performance, reliability, and endurance." and other seemingly reassuring phrases "WD Purple SC microSD cards are designed for continuous 24/7 recordingshould cameras lose connection with the NVR, providing additional confidence in your security video solution."

Comment: Does it make sense to use `time badblocks -sv /dev/mmcblk0p2 -o mmcblk0p2.log` to follow the evolution of badblocks as suggested [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/251/how-can-i-determine-when-an-sd-card-needs-replacement)?

Comment: I see some OS level (Debian 11 for me) info that may contain useful info in `/sys/block/mmcblk2/integrity/` and neighboring folders ... who knows ... more info [here](https://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/sd-memory-card-faq/reading-sd-card-cid-serial-psn-internal-numbers/)

Comment: WD Purple are good quality and not too pricey and your usage pattern sounds low enough. I suggest to just take the plunge.

Comment: Dropbox for linux does not work with exFAT. I have not seen it written anywhere ... until I run it and changed the dropbox folder to the exFAT partition. Dropbox only runs on ext4 partitions. So I have made an ext4 partition and I have disabled journaling.

Comment: I am up-voting your comments, but the answer has to do with dropbox being able to work only with ext4, so I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that [Dropbox works only with Ext4 on 32-bit systems](https://help.dropbox.com/installs/system-requirements), so the question has only one answer due to the limitation of dropbox on linux. BTRFS was not listed by my dropbox gui as an actually available option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).